# Show Sharepoint list data into external Html website

Tags: sharepoint-online, html

My boss asked me today if it is possible to use Sharepoint list data into an external HTML website...
in fact i have to create a newsletter and the news are already on a sharepoint site.

They are publishing news on their sharepoint but they'd like to recover the news from the sharepoint list and put them into the home page of the other website.

I saw some different possibilities using Jquery or JavaScript or else Json.

To the effect that i'm not a regular with these languages... 
First question: Is that possible? Because i think the two websites have differents servers. Second one: if yes, how can i do that?

Comment: Yes, and you have to use the approaches you have already listed (javascript with SharePoint Client Object Model, or REST)

Comment: do you have any example of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of Publish your data for public view you need to enable Anonymous access for this announcement and news lists.

Now **Go to List -> List setting -> RSS Setting -> checked required columns -> click OK**

Now open Announcement List RSS Feed Link form List Ribbon. using this link you can get data in to your HTML site.

In HTML site you can use third party RSS viewer control.

that's it. :)

Comment: Hello Jatin...Great Tips...but i have a problem.
i created my rss feed well...
Then i click on the RSS Feed Link in the List Ribbon.
I get a page with my data.
But then, when i copy/paste the url in my HTML test page...no data appears on my page... 
What did i do wrong? :S


here's the link structure:


mysharepoint/mysite/_layouts/15/listfeed.aspx?List=%7B2226E9A0-5143-4C15-B8BE-6CB35C78A92B%7D&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fmy%2Esharepoint%2Enet%2Fmysite%2FLists%2Fmylist%2FAllItems%2Easpx

Comment: Have you enable anonymous access for this list? due to permission issue it may be happen.

Comment: yes it seems that it was the problem, i figured it out a few minutes after my comment ^^

Comment: Hello, the client doesn't approve the rss feed. Is there any chance to succeed by recover the datas in ASP and then créate an HTML page?

Comment: another way is you can use sharepoint client object model to retrive data from sharepoint list.refer this [link] (http://ojasmaru.blogspot.in/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-get-list-items-using.html)